# Выравнивание элементов по центру в меню bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Как можно выровнять элементы меню по центру, text-center и justify-center не срабатывает, в чём может быть проблема?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class=" navbar-expand-lg navbar" style="background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active menu-item">
        <svg>
          <text x="50%" y="50%" stroke="white" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">Услуги</text>
          <rect></rect>
        </svg>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item menu-item">
        <svg>
          <text x="50%" y="50%" stroke="white" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">Контакты</text>
          <rect></rect>
        </svg>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дайте блоку `width: 100%;` и потом `text-center` и `justify-center`

Comment: для какого именно блока это прописать?

Comment: напишите в каком месте вам нужно выровнять все?

Comment: мне нужно выровнять элементы меню